# Were the writers of Voyager: Cathexis influenced by the TNG: Lonely Among Us episode?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-tng, star-trek-voyager, character-similarity

Does anyone else see the parallels and similar aspects between the following two episodes:

- Star trek Voyager: Cathexis    (1X13)
- Star Trek TNG: Lonely Among Us (1X07)

Have any of the writers or anyone mentioned the parallels?

**In the sense that in [Voyager](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cathexis_(Star_Trek:_Voyager)):**

> Tuvok reveals that he is a noncorporeal alien known as the Komar, seeking to bring Voyager's crew to the center of the **nebula** so that his people can feed on their neural energy;

and

> Once the Doctor is back on-line, he is able to restore Chakotay's mind to his body, and recover Kes from her coma.

**And in [TNG](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lonely_Among_Us):**

> Unseen by the crew, Lt. Worf (Michael Dorn) is hit with a strange energy discharge as the ship passes the **cloud**, causing him to become violent

and

> Picard announces that they had picked up an entity previously when they passed the **cloud**, and now Picard and the entity are one. Under its influence, Picard plans to transport himself back into the cloud, and he shoots energy at the bridge crew when they try to stop him. The crew are unable to prevent Picard from beaming off the ship. The crew spend hours trying to locate Picard to no avail, so they are forced to accept he is beyond recovery and prepare to leave. However, Troi senses the Captain's essence nearby, and Picard manages to signal the crew through the ship's computers. Data is able to reverse the transport, reconstituting Picard without the entity.

So similarities, in both TNG and Voyager episodes:

- We came across two similar types of life forms that are non-corporeal "energy creatures".
- It happened that a human was also converted into an "energy state" (Picard vs Chakotey).
- It happened that the energy life forms controlled a human body (Picard vs Tuvov).
- In Voyager it was a **nebula**, and in **TNG** it was a cloud. But a nebula is a type of cloud adding to the similarity:

> A **nebula** (Latin for "**cloud**" or "fog"; pl. nebulae, nebulæ, or nebulas) is an interstellar cloud of dust, hydrogen, helium and other ionized gases. Originally, nebula was a name for any diffuse astronomical object, including galaxies beyond the Milky Way.

So basically, the similarities point that these two types of energy life form are actually quite similar.

**Were the writers in Voyager influenced by the TNG episode?**

Comment: If the Voyager writers were not influenced by the whole of the TNG cannon, wouldn't that represent a huge failure to understand the universe they're writing about?

Comment: I've edited to make this seem like your less asking for an opinion and more asking about official statements (as that is what I believe you were asking anyway). I've also edited to make your title clearer, remember titles are the main thing that draw people to your question, it's best to have it descriptive and to the point.

Comment: Are there any voyager episodes that are not influenced by anything in Star trek? If you are looking for something that is completely original, watch ds9. It certainly has nothing to do with the other shows or any other show on tv with the budget to hire professional actors and writers

Comment: @Raditz_35 Maybe I'm missing your point, but completely original?  The opening of the first episode starts off with Picard when he was Locutus, the Bajoran occupation and its people were first covered in TNG with Ensign Ro, O'Brien and later Worf were characters well established in TNG before appearing in DS9, and, if I remember correctly, later the Maquis movement first started in TNG.

Comment: If I wanted to watch "Days of Our Lives (in outer space)" then I'd watch DS9.  Else, any of the Star Trek series.

Comment: @Raditz_35:   I sure think most of what happened in "Threshold" wasn't influenced by previous *Star Trek*....

Comment: Jontia, a cannon is a huge gun.

Comment: There can be dozens upon dozens of similar questions. Were the writers of "The Naked Now" influenced by the writers of "The Naked Time"? Were the writers of "If Wishes Were Horses" influenced by the writers of "Shore Leave"? Were the writers of "Encounter at Farpoint" influenced by the writers of "The Squire of Gothos"? Etc.

Comment: @HamSandwich that goes off if not watched closely? :)

Comment: @HamSandwich I challenge you to find that many episodes that have so many parallels!

Comment: @Jontia , yes but invisible energy like cloud creatures able to inhabit humans were not part of the permanent recurring established stories. Unless ofcourse you count the prophets also hmmm